# Shiny with flexdashboard, dataframe as variable

Tags: r, variables, shiny, fread, flexdashboard

Using shiny within Flexdashboard I want to plot and display a dataframe where this dataframe is a variable from an input in my sidebar:

````
Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("df", label = h3("Select df"),  choices = list("january" = "df1", "february" = "df2"))
```
````

I'm then plotting and displaying my dataframe inside a tabset:

````
Row {.tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Plot
```{r}
renderPlot({
plot(fread(paste("/Users/woshitom/Desktop/shiny/",input$df,".csv",sep="")),type="o", col="blue")
})
```

### Data
```{r}
renderTable(fread(paste("/Users/woshitom/Desktop/shiny/",input$df,".csv",sep="")))
```
````

As you can see I'm loading 2 times my csv:

```
fread(paste("/Users/woshitom/Desktop/shiny/",input$df,".csv",sep=""))
```

Instead I'd like to store it in a variable:

```
my_df <- fread(paste("/Users/woshitom/Desktop/shiny/",input$df,".csv",sep=""))
```

But when I do so I'm getting the following error:

```
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Any idea how i should store this dataframe?

Comment: try with `my_df <- reactive({fread(paste("/Users/woshitom/Desktop/shiny/",input$df,".csv",sep=""))})`

Comment: thanks! works fine, please submit your answer i'm gonna validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiny inputs should be used inside render functions, observers or reactives. This is why you are getting the error. In your case since you want to store the result in a variable the way to go is to create a reactive variable with reactive(). This is the soltution:

```
my_df <- reactive({fread(paste("/Users/woshitom/Desktop/shiny/",input‌​$df,".csv",sep=""))}‌​)
```